# SSIS Excel Destination with format

Tags: ssis

I try to export excel file with some format like:
Interior.Color
HorizontalAlignment
Font.Bold
and etc..
So the question is, can we do like that is SSIS..
and how to do it?

Answer (score 4):

Not natively no.

If you always have the same output format you could create a formatted template spreadsheet, then make a copy of that to fill with data. I have seen this done before, the formulas and formatting were in the template, the SSIS job copied the template, then populated the copy.

Answer (score 2):

SSIS is primarily a tool for moving data.  Although it may be possible to write a script task or a custom component to do what you want, a better way would be to use a tool that is designed for presentation of data (a reporting tool, for example: SSRS) to do what you are trying to do.